# Rails SQLite check returning double

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm using Rails to search through a SQLite table (for other reasons I can't use the standard database-model system) using a SELECT query like so:

`info = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM #{form_name} WHERE EmailAddress = \"#{user_em}\";")`

This returns the correct values, but for some reason the output is in duplicate, the difference being the 2nd set doesn't have column titles in the hash, instead going from 0-[num columns]. For example:

`{"id"=>1, "Timestamp"=>"2/27/2017 14:26:03", "EmailAddress"=>"-snip-", 0=>1, 1=>"2/27/2017 14:26:03", 2=>"-snip-"}`

(I'll note the obvious- there's only one row in the table with that information in it)

While it's not exactly a fatal problem, I'm interested as to why it's doing so and if it's possible to prevent it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allows you to read the values both by column index or column name:

```
id        = row[0]
timestamp = row["Timestamp"]
```

Comment: Ah, so it's intentional? I suppose that would make a deal of sense in general usage. It's easier for my system to shove it in an array and iterate (tables and created and destroyed programmatically), but that's useful info for the future. Thank you!